# Group Summary Disappears When Grid is Refreshed/Re-Drawn

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs-grid, extjs5

Back again with another ExtJS query. I have a grid with a SummaryGroup feature that is toggle-able (enabled/disabled) from a tool button on the panel header. Enabling once displays it properly, disable then try enable the feature. The grouping happens but the Summery totals of the groups doesn't come back again?

**JS fiddle here**: http://jsfiddle.net/hD4C4/1/

In the fiddle it will show the group totals then if you disable and re-enable again they disappear?

Here is a picture of pressing the button once:
[image]

Here is the same grid after disabling it then re-enabling it again:
[image]

Below is the toggle code on the panel header tool button:

```
 xtype: 'tool',
            type: 'expand',
            tooltip: 'Enable grouping',
            handler: function(e, target, panelHeader, tool){
                var serviceGridView = Ext.getCmp('serviceOverview').getView('groupingFeature'),
                    gridFeature = serviceGridView.getFeature('serviceOverviewGroupingFeature');
                if (tool.type == 'expand') {
                    gridFeature.enable();
                    tool.setType('collapse');
                    tool.setTooltip('Disable grouping');
                } else {
                    gridFeature.disable();
                    Ext.getCmp('serviceOverview').setLoading(false,false);
                    Ext.getCmp('serviceOverview').getStore().reload();
                    tool.setType('expand');
                    tool.setTooltip('Enable grouping');
                }
            }
```

And here is my grid code (with the feature function at the top:

```
var groupingFeature = Ext.create('Ext.grid.feature.GroupingSummary', {
    groupHeaderTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
        '',
        '{name:this.formatName} ({rows.length})',
        {
            formatName: function(name) {
                return '<span style="color: #3892d3;">' + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1) + '</span>';
            }
        }
    ),
    hideGroupedHeader: false,
    startCollapsed: true,
    showSummaryRow: true,
    id: 'serviceOverviewGroupingFeature'
});

Ext.define('APP.view.core.grids.Serviceoverview', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.gridportlet',

    height: 'auto',
    id: 'serviceOverview',
    cls: 'productsGrid',
    viewConfig: {
        loadMask: true
    },

    features: [groupingFeature, {ftype: 'summary'}],

    initComponent: function(){

        var store = Ext.create('APP.store.Serviceoverview');

        Ext.apply(this, {
            height: this.height,
            store: store,
            stripeRows: true,
            columnLines: true,
            columns: [{
                id       :'service-product',
                text   : 'Product',
                flex: 1,
                sortable : true,
                dataIndex: 'PACKAGE',
                summaryType: function(records) {
                    if (typeof records[0] !== 'undefined') {
                        var myGroupName = records[0].get('LISTING');

                        if (this.isStore) {
                            return '<span style="font-weight: bold;">Total of all</span>';
                        }

                        return '<span style="font-weight: bold;">'+myGroupName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + myGroupName.slice(1)+' Totals</span>';
                        //return '<span style="font-weight: bold;">Totals</span>';
                    }
                },
                renderer: function(value, metaData ,record) {
                    return value;
                }
            },{
                id       :'service-listing',
                text   : 'Listing',
                flex: 1,
                sortable : true,
                dataIndex: 'LISTING',
                renderer: function(value, metaData ,record){
                    return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1);
                }
            },{
                id       :'service-total',
                text   : 'Running Total',
                flex: 1,
                sortable : true,
                dataIndex: 'TOTAL',
                summaryType: function(values) {
                    var total=0.0;
                    Ext.Array.forEach(values, function (record){
                        if (record.data.TOTAL !== null) {
                            total += parseFloat(record.data.TOTAL);
                        }
                    });
                    return '<span style="font-weight: bold;">&pound;' + numeral(total.toFixed(2)).format('0,0.00') + '</span>';
                },
                renderer: function(value, metaData ,record){
                    if (value == null) {
                        return '&pound;0.00';
                    }
                    return '&pound;' + numeral(value).format('0,0.00');
                }
            },{
                id       :'service-total-paid',
                text   : 'Total Paid',
                flex: 1,
                sortable : true,
                dataIndex: 'TOTAL_PAID',
                summaryType: function(values) {
                    var total=0.0;
                    Ext.Array.forEach(values, function (record){
                        if (record.data.TOTAL_PAID !== null) {
                            total += parseFloat(record.data.TOTAL_PAID);
                        }
                    });
                    return '<span style="font-weight: bold;">&pound;' + numeral(total.toFixed(2)).format('0,0.00') + '</span>';
                },
                renderer: function(value, metaData ,record){
                    if (value == null) {
                        return '&pound;0.00';
                    }
                    return '&pound;' + numeral(value).format('0,0.00');
                }
            },{
                id       :'service-outstanding',
                text   : 'Outstanding',
                flex: 1,
                sortable : true,
                dataIndex: 'OUTSTANDING',
                summaryType: function(values) {
                    var total=0.0;
                    Ext.Array.forEach(values, function (record){
                        if (record.data.OUTSTANDING !== null) {
                            total += parseFloat(record.data.OUTSTANDING);
                        }
                    });
                    return '<span style="font-weight: bold;">&pound;' + numeral(total.toFixed(2)).format('0,0.00') + '</span>';
                },
                renderer: function(value, metaData ,record){
                    if (value == null) {
                        return '&pound;0.00';
                    }
                    return '&pound;' + numeral(value).format('0,0.00');
                }
            },{
                id       :'service-properties',
                text   : 'No. of Clients',
                flex: 1,
                sortable : true,
                 dataIndex: 'CLIENTS',
                summaryType: function(values) {
                    var total=0.0;
                    Ext.Array.forEach(values, function (record){
                        if (record.data.CLIENTS !== null) {
                            total += parseFloat(record.data.CLIENTS);
                        }
                    });
                    return '<span style="font-weight: bold;">' + total + '</span>';
                }
            },{
                id       :'service-average-total',
                text   : 'Av. Total',
                flex: 1,
                sortable : true,
                dataIndex: 'AVERAGE_TOTAL',
                summaryType: function(values) {
                    var total=0.0;
                    Ext.Array.forEach(values, function (record){
                        if (record.data.AVERAGE_TOTAL !== null) {
                            total += parseFloat(record.data.AVERAGE_TOTAL);
                        }
                    });
                    return '<span style="font-weight: bold;">&pound;' + numeral(total.toFixed(2)).format('0,0.00') + '</span>';
                },
                renderer: function(value, metaData ,record){
                    if (value == null) {
                        return '&pound;0.00';
                    }
                    return '&pound;' + numeral(value).format('0,0.00');
                }
            },{
                id       :'service-average-total-paid',
                text   : 'Av. Total Paid',
                flex: 1,
                sortable : true,
                dataIndex: 'AVERAGE_TOTAL_PAID',
                summaryType: function(values) {
                    var total=0.0;
                    Ext.Array.forEach(values, function (record){
                        if (record.data.AVERAGE_TOTAL_PAID !== null) {
                            total += parseFloat(record.data.AVERAGE_TOTAL_PAID);
                        }
                    });
                    return '<span style="font-weight: bold;">&pound;' + numeral(total.toFixed(2)).format('0,0.00') + '</span>';
                },
                renderer: function(value, metaData ,record){
                    if (value == null) {
                        return '&pound;0.00';
                    }
                    return '&pound;' + numeral(value).format('0,0.00');
                }
            },{
                id       :'service-average-outstanding',
                text   : 'Av. Outstanding',
                flex: 1,
                sortable : true,
                dataIndex: 'AVERAGE_OUTSTANDING',
                summaryType: function(values) {
                    var total=0.0;
                    Ext.Array.forEach(values, function (record){
                        if (record.data.AVERAGE_OUTSTANDING !== null) {
                            total += parseFloat(record.data.AVERAGE_OUTSTANDING);
                        }
                    });
                    return '<span style="font-weight: bold;">&pound;' + numeral(total.toFixed(2)).format('0,0.00') + '</span>';
                },
                renderer: function(value, metaData ,record){
                    if (value == null) {
                        return '&pound;0.00';
                    }
                    return '&pound;' + numeral(value).format('0,0.00');
                }
            }]
        });

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Thank you in advance :)
Nathan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like bug.

I have analyzed code a bit, and I discovered that this issue is caused by `generateSummaryData` method in feature. In this method you can find this code:

```
if (hasRemote || store.updating || groupInfo.lastGeneration !== group.generation) {
    record = me.populateRecord(group, groupInfo, remoteData);

    if (!lockingPartner || (me.view.ownerCt === me.view.ownerCt.ownerLockable.normalGrid)) {
        groupInfo.lastGeneration = group.generation;
    }
} else {
    record = me.getAggregateRecord(group);
}
```

When grid is firstly rendered first branch is executed for all groups, and after reenabling - second branch. Calling `getAggregateRecord` instead of `populateRecord` produces empty summary record. I didn't go any deeper, so for now I can only give you dirty hack to override this (it forces code to enter first branch):

```
store.updating = true;
feature.enable();
store.updating = false;
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P2e7s/6/

---

After some more digging I've found out that most likely this issue occurs because `group.generation` is not incremented when `populateRecord` is called. As a result `group.generation` always equals to `1`, so record is populated only when `lastGeneration` is empty (first code pass). After re-enabling feature, new groups are created, but they also have `generation` set to `1`.

So I've came up with less dirty hack:

```
Ext.define('Ext.override.grid.feature.AbstractSummary', {
    override: 'Ext.grid.feature.GroupingSummary',
    populateRecord: function (group, groupInfo, remoteData) {
        ++group.generation;
        return this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

With that override, you can simply enable feature, and it should work.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P2e7s/9/

Comment: You're a star @Lolo :) Really appreciate your time on this issue. Even going away to figure out a less dirty method, many thanks :)

Comment: I had a very similar issue and both of your workarounds works, thanks!